# How can I set margin to one element of two elements which are next to each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.fold1_content .logo{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fold1_content .title{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fold1_content">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="title">         
    title   
  </div>
</div>
```

All I'm trying to do is set `.title{margin-top: 30px;}`. I mean I want to bring that title down a little bit. How can I do that?

Currently neither `padding` nor `margin` will not affect only on one element.

Comment: An image of what you're trying to achieve would definitely help, since *down a little bit* is quite imprecise...

Comment: you can do whatever you want to do by using + css selector.
example: 
.first{margin:10px}
.first+.secound{margin:10px}

Answer (score 2):

you have to use **vertical-align** property. For more info [vertical-align property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

```css
.fold1_content .logo{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fold1_content .title{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="fold1_content">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="title">
    title
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use + css selector it would select just next item of your current class.

I made the changes in your code. I think it might helpful.

```css
.fold1_content .logo{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
.fold1_content .title{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.fold1_content .logo + .title {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fold1_content">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="title">
        title
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try positioning your divs, if that doesn't bother:

```css
.fold1_content {
    position: relative;
}

.fold1_content .logo{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
.fold1_content .title{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 60px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fold1_content">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="title">
        title
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fold1_content {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;  //only if you need both div to equally space
}
.fold1_content .logo{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fold1_content .title{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fold1_content">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="title">
    title
  </div>
</div>
```

Try Flexbox it gives better output

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left; or float:right; to both of your elements then your margin should work as expected. 
Best of luck!

```
<style>
.fold1_content .logo{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
}
.fold1_content .title{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 60px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}
</style>
<div class="fold1_content">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="title">
        title
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here yo go with one more solution

```css
.fold1_content .logo{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fold1_content .title{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 60px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="fold1_content">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="title">
    title
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fold1_content{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
 }
    .fold1_content .logo{
        border: 1px solid;

        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .fold1_content .title{
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        font-size: 60px;


    }
```

```html
    <div class="fold1_content">
        <div class="logo">logo</div>
        <div class="title">
            title
        </div>
    </div>



Try flex property, it's awesome.
```